# Adding Categories to Classes in Pharo 9.0 (Smalltalk)

Tags: class, categories, smalltalk, pharo

I've very recently started learning Pharo Smalltalk and my first assignment requires me to add three categories to a class, but the problem is that any information I find on the web is written before 2014, and the options are just not there anymore. How can I add categories to classes in Pharo 9.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that the assignment consists in adding categories programmatically. In that case, this is how you could learn how to add a category.

1. Find the class you want to add the category to
2. Inspect the class and take a look to its instvars
3. The categories of the class should be there somehow
4. The ivar whose name looks promising is `organization`
5. Its class is `ClassOrganizer`
6. Check to see whether there is a `ClassOrganizerTest` for testing it
7. Found! Take a look at the tests and see if you can find what you are looking for.